# A word to describe not fully knowing someone fully?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Let's say a person doesn't fully know person and they "know" that person for a long time now, but you only know basic stuff about them, like what their likes, dislikes, but never fully dwelled deeper than that. You never knew how they came to be the person they became today or who they were when they were young, or what experiences shaped them to become the person they are today. I'm trying to write a song that has that special meaning to the person I'm describing.

Comment: Their 'acquaintance', for example?

Comment: Yes, their "acquaintance".

Comment: Can meaning also apply to loved ones?

Comment: Why does the title of this question have the word *fully* used twice?

Comment: By the way, this question might be closed: *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)*. You may want to [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/403432/edit)

Comment: Do you have any words of the song yet? We *might* be able to come up with something more fitting. PS, check out https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19358/are-there-commonly-used-words-to-denote-different-gradations-of-friendship-in-en

Answer (score 1):

**Acquaintance**

> a person known to one, but usually not a close friend.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/acquaintance)

Comment: This is an answer to the previous question 'Are there commonly used words to denote different gradations of friendship in English?'; if the question is interpreted as licensing this answer, it is a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks, I'll try and come up with something new...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't think of anything better, unfortunately. If the community/moderators/OP consider it a dupe, they'll say so... (The OP has confirmed that 'acquaintance' is indeed what they were looking for)

Comment: Suggesting this in a 'comment' is the correct way to help OP while not sanctioning the question.